# C++ integer multiplication: explain this behaviour

Tags: c++, overflow

I wrote a simple function in C++ to calculate the volume of a Box object which has a length, breadth, and height. This is part of a class, so `l,b,h` are private members:

```
long long CalculateVolume(){
        return l*b*h;
}
```

This does not work correctly with large values of `l,b,h`. In my case `l = 1039, b = 3749, h = 8473`. The result was

```
-1355615565
```

I thought this was due to overflow, so I tried

```
unsigned long long CalculateVolume(){
        return l*b*h;
}
```

but the result was

```
18446744072353936051
```

Finally, what worked was to multiply the integers in steps:

```
long long CalculateVolume(){
        long long result = l;
        result *= b;
        result *= h;
        return result;
}
```

which gave the correct result of `33004122803`. I don't understand why this solution works. Can you explain what happens under the hood in each of the three cases? Thank you!

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  We don't know where `l`, `b`, or `h` come from in your earlier examples (and no, description of what they are is not enough -- descriptions don't always tell the truth).

Comment: whatever the return type of *CalculateVolume* when the overflow already occurred in _l*b*h_

Comment: This is what happens if you mix your types. `1LL * l * b * h` is a fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you variables `l`, `b`, and `h` are `long long` then the behaviour of both snippets would be identical.

However, if the variables are `int`s, then in the first snippet

```
return l * b * h;
```

would result in an overflow. The conversion to `long long` would only happen when the result is *returned*, which is too late.

In this snippet

```
long long result = l;
result *= b;           // multiplying 'int' and 'long long' is like multiplying 2 'long long's
result *= h;
return result;
```

you are only ever multiplying `long long`s, so you don't overflow.

You could make your variables `long long` to begin with, or cast the variables before multiplying.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the types of your 3 variables:l, b, and h are responsible for the wrong behavior, if they are integers values, their multiplication is an integer as well. So you have to cast them to long long or unsigned long long before multiplying. Or like you did in the last snippet of code, you can cast only one of them and then the multiplication will have the biggest type between the factors (which is in that case long long)